# Can an ashx script be executed from a SQL Server Agent Step?

Tags: c#, sql-server, jobs, ashx, agent

I currently have a .vbs file being run at a daily time scheduled in a SQL Server 2005 Server Agent Job.

The "Job Step Properties" dialog contains:

**Type**: "Operating system (CmdExec)"

and the **Command** value is as follows:

"cscript d:\sites\mysite\myscheduled\script_to_run.vbs"

This works fine but I've had to upgrade the script and am now hoping to use an .ashx handler file in its place. Does anyone know how to configure the Job to execute an ashx handler file? What would the "Type" be? ActiveX Script? What would the "Command" be before the path reference? I don't want to use Task Scheduler, etc., but just want to know if it's possible to execute an ashx file in a Server Agent Job and if so what to set the "Type" and "Command" values to. Many TIA.

Comment: Why do you want to introduce a web server into the middle of all of this? Can you describe exactly what the ashx handler does, and why you had to "upgrade"?

Comment: The .vbs file was emailing a small number of invoices on a recurring basis with minimal bounces, complaints, etc. Some new marketing brought on board the need for quite large numbers of invoices needing emailing and I'm using Amazon.com's emailing services in which they supply a SDK with a library that the  C# ashx file is referencing for emailing credential purposes to overcome Spam and complaint issues through domain verification, etc. Using an ashx file (or even .vbs files) in this context isn't something I'm very familiar with having only used them quite extensively in a website context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a CmdExec step for this.

```c#
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://wherever/your_handler.ashx"
```

You won't see the browser window open, and it may require elevated rights for the SQL Server or proxy account, but it should work.

You can also do something similar by invoking a PowerShell script using a PowerShell step type instead.

Or you could just change your VBScript to do something like this:

```vbs
set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmd     = """C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"" " & _
          "http://wherever/your_handler.ashx"
wsh.Run cmd
set wsh = Nothing
```

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly. Thank you, I really appreciate that. Your "PowerShell script" suggestion I will also look more into.

Comment: After trying both of the examples you supplied, the first being iexplore.exe as the Command to execute "http://wherever/your_handler.ashx" and the second a .vbs file accomplishing the same thing I cannot get it to work. Initially when I tried the first example I could have swore it worked sending emails but having attempted repeated times it just is not running the ashx script. If I run the .vbs scipt example in Internet Explorer it works fine, emails are sent but configuring the command (cscript) running in Server Agent job the vbs does not run the ashx script (no emails sent). And no errors.

Comment: Sorry for the yo-yo'ing comments here with success/no-success. The solutions supplied by @aaronbertrand is/are working fine after all, what happened was I did a manual "Start Job" in Server Agent to test and did not manually "Stop Job" so each time the day/time test settings passed the Step couldn't start as it reported "already started" due to my manual "Start Job". After stopping the manual start job the day/time executions began working fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

an ashx handler file is an aspnet file so it works in a website.
So, SQL Server agent can't execute this type of file.
If you want to do some scheduled task, it's better to use a console application (writting on csharp ;-).
Best regard

Comment: While @AaronBertrand supplied the solution that works immediately for me I have noted your suggestion to look at a C# console application as well. Thank you.